# find the previous is textnode from classname

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<p>
   <ins>this is sample text</ins> here text node 
   <span class='cursor'></span><ins>last word</ins>
</p>


$('.cursor').prev()
```

is returning the previous `ins` tag.

How to find `span.cursor` before `here text node`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
$('.cursor')[0].previousSibling
```

Answer (score 2):

Your question is marginally unclear, but I'm interpreting it to mean that you wish to recover the `textNode` (containing the text of `here text node`) prior to the `<span class="cursor">`?

If that's the case then jQuery can manage it with the following:

```js
// here we find the '.cursor' element, and then
// using prop('previousSibling') we recover the
// previousSibling node of the first '.cursor'
// in the collection:
var node = $('.cursor').prop('previousSibling'),

// here we recover the nodeValue (the text) of the
// recovered previousSibling (textNode) node:
  text = node.nodeValue;

console.log(text);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p><ins>this is sample text</ins> here text node <span class='cursor'></span><ins>last word</ins>
```

If you'd rather recover all such `textNode`s, if you have multiple `<span class="cursor">` elements, then we can, instead, use:

```js
// here we again select all '.cursor' elements, and then
// filter that collection, using filter():
var nodes = $('.cursor').filter(function() {
    // we retain only those elements for which the
    // following statement returns a truthy statement,
    // if there is no previousSibling the evaluation
    // results in null, and so is discarded:
    return this.previousSibling;
  // here we use map() to create an array-like
  // structure:
  }).map(function() {

    // here we return the previousSibling node
    // to the collection:
    return this.previousSibling;
  }),

  // here we create an array-like collection
  // of the text of those found nodes, using map():
  text = nodes.map(function() {

    // returning the nodeValue (the text) of the node:
    return this.nodeValue;

  // using get() to convert the array-like collection
  // into an Array:
  }).get();

console.log(text);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p><ins>this is sample text</ins> here text node <span class='cursor'></span><ins>last word</ins>
</p>
<p><span class='cursor'></span><ins>last word</ins>
</p>
<p><ins>this is sample text</ins> here is another text node <span class='cursor'></span><ins>last word</ins>
</p>
```

Of course it's worth pointing out that jQuery offers nothing over plain JavaScript in this problem, and may perhaps be a little more difficult. With plain JavaScript you could use the simple form of:

```js
// here we use Array.from() to convert the Array-like collection
// returned by document.querySelectorAll() into an Array:
var cursors = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.cursor')),

  // here we filter the Array of cursor element-nodes
  // using Array.prototype.filter():
  nodes = cursors.filter(function(cursorNode) {
    // cursorNode is a reference to the current
    // node of the Array of nodes over which we're
    // iterating.

    // here we retain only those cursorNodes that 
    // have a previous sibling:
    return cursorNode.previousSibling;

    // using Array.prototype.map() to create an Array:
  }).map(function(cursorNode) {

    // returning the previous sibling of the
    // current cursorNode to the newly-formed
    // Array:
    return cursorNode.previousSibling;
  }),

  // here we iterate over the nodesArray, again
  // using Array.prototype.map():
  text = nodes.map(function(node) {
    // node is a reference to the current node
    // of the array of nodes over which we're
    // currently iterating.

    // here we return the nodeValue of the current node:
    return node.nodeValue;
  });

console.log(text);
```

```html
<p><ins>this is sample text</ins> here text node <span class='cursor'></span><ins>last word</ins>
</p>
<p><span class='cursor'></span><ins>last word</ins>
</p>
<p><ins>this is sample text</ins> here is another text node <span class='cursor'></span><ins>last word</ins>
</p>
```

It's worth noting that, because I assumed a lack of familiarity with the approach, the above JavaScript versions are less concise than they could be; to abbreviate them it's possible to simply write the following:

```js
var previousTexts = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.cursor'))
  .filter(function(cursorNode) {
    return cursorNode.previousSibling;
  }).map(function(cursorNode) {
    return cursorNode.previousSibling.nodeValue;
  });

console.log(previousTexts);
```

```html
<p><ins>this is sample text</ins> here text node <span class='cursor'></span><ins>last word</ins>
</p>
<p><span class='cursor'></span><ins>last word</ins>
</p>
<p><ins>this is sample text</ins> here is another text node <span class='cursor'></span><ins>last word</ins>
</p>
```

And, if you – or your users – are working with ES6 compatible browsers it can of course be written even more concisely using Arrow function syntax (though please note that brevity is *not* the primary goal of writing scripts, they first need to be understandable by those following you):

```js
var previousTexts = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.cursor'))
  .filter(cursorNode => cursorNode.previousSibling)
  .map(cursorNode => cursorNode.previousSibling.nodeValue);

console.log(previousTexts);
```

```html
<p><ins>this is sample text</ins> here text node <span class='cursor'></span><ins>last word</ins>
</p>
<p><span class='cursor'></span><ins>last word</ins>
</p>
<p><ins>this is sample text</ins> here is another text node <span class='cursor'></span><ins>last word</ins>
</p>
```

References:

- JavaScript:

  - [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from).
  - [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).
  - [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).
  - [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).
  - [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).
  - [`Node.nodeValue`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeValue).
  - [`Node.previousSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/previousSibling).
- jQuery:

  - [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter).
  - [`map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map).
  - [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop).

Comment: It is still sad to see great answer on SO not getting all the attention it deserves... :(

Comment: The other answer is, admittedly, far more simple to understand and implement in limited cases. I suspect that as soon as the OP, or future visitors, encounter a situation in which they have multiple instances of an element whose `previousSibling` they need to retrieve then they might find this answer and upvote accordingly. We play the long game, Mr. Wolff! ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can find the text not using native code:

```js
console.log(document.getElementsByClassName('cursor')[0].previousSibling.nodeValue)
```

```html
<p><ins>this is sample text</ins> here text node <span class='cursor'></span><ins>last word</ins>
```

Comment: Do bear in mind that users of Internet Explorer 8, and below, [might encounter problems](http://caniuse.com/#search=getelementsbyclassname); oddly enough `document.querySelectorAll('.cursor')` would be more compatible, at least [in version 8 and above](http://caniuse.com/#search=queryselectorall), though admittedly with a tiny user-base it's probably of little importance.